# Programmatically detect lost url connection

Tags: url, connection, detect

I am using the ole object Shell.Explorer.2 to display a web page inside my form.  I need to be able to detect if the connection to the server/url is lost.

I imagine that if either the server went down or the the internet connection was disrupted, the connection to the server would be lost.  I want to close my form if the connection is lost.  No reconnects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

InternetCheckConnection()

That is the answer.  Thank you Mr. Berezniker

```
#DEFINE  FLAG_ICC_FORCE_CONNECTION 1
DECLARE LONG InternetCheckConnection IN Wininet.DLL ;
    STRING Url, ;
    LONG dwFlags, ;
    LONG Reserved
 
* Fast and reliable web site
lcUrl = "http://www.google.com"
 
IF InternetCheckConnection(lcUrl, FLAG_ICC_FORCE_CONNECTION, 0) <> 0
    ? "Connection is available"
ELSE
    ? "No Connection"
ENDIF
```